# Primes of the form $a+b^k$ for $k=(a \bmod 2),\ldots,n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, experimental-mathematics

**Procrastinal problem:** Given $n$, one can ask for integers $a,b>1$ of different parities
such that $a+b^k$ is prime  for $k=(a\bmod 2),\ldots,n$.

A few examples are:

$2+4995825^k$ is prime for $k=0,\ldots,6$.

$1708+6301^k$ is prime for $k=0,\ldots,8$.

$4503+4^k$ is prime for $k=1,\ldots,14$.

*Given $n$, do there exist sets of primes of the form $\lbrace a+b^k,k=(a \bmod 2)\ldots,n\rbrace$?*

*Do there exist such sets with fixed $a\geq 2$, with fixed $b\geq 2$?
Given $n$, can one say something on 'smallest' such sets (say with $a+b$ minimal, or with $ab$ minimal)?*

*Are such sets necessarily finite?* (The existence of such an infinite
set of primes would be very surprising, see also [Density of primes in sequences of the form $a^n+b$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268918/density-of-primes-in-sequences-of-the-form-anb))

(Stupid observation: $x^3+1=(x-1)(x^2-x+1)$ implies that $a=1$ is not interesting.)

Comment: There is no prime $p$ such that $4^k$, $k=1,2,\dots,n$ covers all the residue classes mod $p$ (since $4$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$, its powers can only be quadratic residues), so those powers of four constitute an *admissible set*. Then standard (but unproved) conjectures imply that for each $n$ there exist $a$ such that $a+4^k$ is prime for $1\le k\le n$.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I do not understand the link between admissibility and primality: Is admissibility a necessary prerequisites for the conjectures?

Comment: If you have a prime $p$ and a set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ of positive integers which covers all congruence classes modulo $p$, then you can't have $m\ge p$ such that $m+a_i$, $1\le i\le n$, are all prime. E.g., $m+2$, $m+4$, $m+6$ can't all be prime (for $m>1$) since one of them will be a multiple of three, but $m+2$, $m+4$, $m+8$ can all be prime and, conjecturally, are all prime for infinitely many $m$. We say $\{2,4,8\}$ is admissible, $\{2,4,6\}$ isn't. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple#Admissibility

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed aware of this: $b$ (the basis of powers) tends to have many small prime-divisors. Your observation implies that $b$ is a perfect square if it is fixed and $n$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Procrastination comment. If I fix $a=2$, I find (with a small PARI/GP function) "good" $b$ values `909`, `4995825` (your example), `28212939`. Searching OEIS gives [A245510](https://oeis.org/A245510); they do not have better examples.

Comment: That OEIS entry was updated now.